# Accidentally deleted gcc5-base and now i can't find any of the common commands

Tags: 14.04, apt

So i've been figuring something on my server through SSH and i accidentally removed the gcc5-base , which resulted in losing packages like apt and other main dependencies

How do i fix this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-5/gcc-5-base_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

and then

```
sudo dpkg -i gcc-5-base_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Should reinstall gcc-5, and probably only gcc-5